# Convert a List<object[]> to List<object> where the count of object[] is dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

How could we convert a `List<object[]>` to `List<object>` where the count of objects in `object[]` is dynamic(*in a single collection it is the same i.e. `items[0].count` is equal to `items[1].count` but every different collection could have a dynamic number of item count)*.

**Sample Data**:
[image: sample data]

What I tried so far is if the count of items is constant it can be achieved by the below code

```
dt.Select().Select(s => s.ItemArray).Select(s => new {a = s[0], b= s[1]}..).ToList()
```

But how could we generate the select statement for the dynamic number of columns?

More background on having the dynamic number of columns:
The `List<object[]>` is generated from `dataRows`. The reason it is dynamic is because `dataTable` could have any number of columns.

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: select many will flatten to a single List I need each row as an separate object

Comment: usually when I see something like "dataTable could have any number of columns" there's actually just specs missing about your db-schema, which usually isn't *that* dynamic. That is usually your database-schema doesn't change from day to day and thus the tables and types used in the databse are pretty much static. Having said this you should get the schema and use it in some Object-relational-mapper such as Entity Framwework, which does all that mapping for you. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `object` is the opposite of dynamic and will actually cause problems if eg you try to store value types like `int` or `struct`. You'll end up with a *new* object wrapping the value. What you posted is a `List<string>`. Generics were create to avoid such problems.

Comment: `The reason it is dynamic is because dataTable could have any number of columns.` that's not a good reason at all. LINQ-over-Dataset works just fine as it is, without losing type information. Column types *don't* change so there's no reason to erase types. That's the opposite of `dynamic` by the way

Comment: A DataTable doesn't contain other DataTables, so where did those arrays come from? Are you trying to flatten two DataTables into one? Have you checked [LINQ to Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/queries-in-linq-to-dataset) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectMany` is what you need, then it doesn't matter how many items are contained in each array:

```
List<object[]> objectArrays = ...
List<object> flattenedObjects = objectArrays.SelectMany(arr => arr).ToList();
```

However, in your screenshot i can see that you have a `DataTable` and you want a list of all fields in all rows, then better use:

```
List<object> allFields = dt.AsEnumerable()
  .SelectMany(row => row.ItemArray)
  .ToList();
```

If you want the most efficient approach:

```
List<object> allFields = new(dt.Rows.Count * dt.Columns.Count);
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) allFields.AddRange(row.ItemArray);
```

Comment: it won't work because the expected output is each row having a different object. what selectMany will do is it will create a single List<object>

Comment: @AmitBisht it works. We can't guess what's going on with your code though. LINQ to Dataset works just fine already, without having to erase DataColumn types.

Comment: @AmitBisht: What means "it won't work", in what way, what is the expected result if not a single, flat `List<object>`? In your question you have asked for a single `List<object>`, in the first comment you say " I need each row as an separate object". So i have no idea what you want.